# web hook to save participants as they connect to a skype for business meeting

Tags: api, lync, skype-for-business

I would like to log the participants to a meeting organized with Skype for Business (Lync), as they connect to the meeting.

Can this be done programatically?

Can you indicate some resources (API, WebHook)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'web' hook to do what you want.  You did not state if you are using Skype for Business on-premise or Skype for Business Online.

You can:

- [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984(v=office.16).aspx) to create a [trusted application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466044(v=office.16).aspx) to log a [hidden user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn465962(v=office.16).aspx) into specific meetings and then 'track' when participants come and go.  The downside is that it's a lot of setup and you can't do it for all meetings but specific meetings that you know about only.  This is not work for Skype for Business Online, only on-premise installs.
- [UCWA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn324971(v=office.16).aspx) to do the same as the UCMA but the user is not 'hidden'.  This should work for both Skype for Business Online and On-premise installs.
- [Trusted Application API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/overview) (which uses UCWA underneath) to do the same as the UCMA above.  This only works on Skype for Business Online only and I *think* the user can be hidden, not sure.
- [Lync Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180.aspx) (this is a older API) to drive a installed Skype windows client to join specific meetings and track as users come and go. Basically the same as UCWA but may be easier to implement as there are more examples / docs for it.
- Use the [Call detail recording](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398570.aspx) to track all calls (not live, but post call complete) and determine if they are conference calls.  This will get pretty involved and will not be a quick solution. This will only work on premise setups only and the CDR has to be enabled for the site.
- [SDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/sdn/articles/skype-for-business-sdn-interface) api to track live calls.  This is like using the CDR but is more like tracking live calls as they happen.  This will get pretty involved and will not be a quick solution. This will only work on premise setups only.
- [Skype Server SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454964.aspx) to create a SIP Proxy application to track live calls.  Of all of the above it's the most complex and most flexible... But it's a lot more work and requires a lot of understanding of the SIP protocols that Skype runs on.  It only works with on-premise installs as well.
- [Skype Server SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454964.aspx) to create a MSPL script to re-direct all conference calls to a UCMA application and then B2BUA the calls back into conference server.  This would allow you to track all conferences but there will be major downsides as the B2BUA call will inhibit some conference features from working.  You *could* redirect the calls instead of using a B2BUA call but you would only be tracking when participants are trying to join and not when they leave.

Those are the only possible solutions that I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you Shane. I'll try the second (UCWA) solution because I'm new to Microsoft and Skype programming. I intend to try to write some python code  for it. Do you know any references?

Comment: Sorry UCWA is the one I know the least about.  The MSDN doc's come from this https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs git repo.  Going through the history can be interesting in trying to figure things out.  Also the WebSDK is built on top of UCWA, so you can use the javascript code as an example of how to use UCWA.  Other than that you have to experiment a lot.